# Android - Inflating a view in a layout makes my layout transparent - How to stop this?

Tags: android, view, layout-inflater, android-inflate

I am trying to inflate a view beneath my layout, but my to layout becomes transparent. Any idea why?

Here is my **mainActivity**:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val rootView = (this.findViewById<View>(android.R.id.content) as ViewGroup)
            .getChildAt(0) as ViewGroup

        val inflater: LayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this)
        val view: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_blueberry, rootView, false)

        rootView.addView(view)
```

my activity layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/flContainer">

    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/rlContainer"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            tools:ignore="UselessParent">
        <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/btStartAnim"
                android:text="start"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and my inflated view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<View
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#abab"
        />
```

This is how it looks: if I add more content it's as transparent as that button. Even weirder considering that I've set a white background in my main layout.

[image]

Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

In inflated view you setted  transparent background thats why issue ocurres.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <View
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#abab"
    />
```

In this please setted proper background without opacity and check once.

```
    android:background="#f00"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val inflater: LayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this)
        val view: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_blueberry, rlContainer, false)
        rlContainer.addView(view)
    }
}
```

Solution images looks like this
[image: Solution images looks like this]

Comment: @rfm here is your problem solution